# Contact Groups in Google People API does not work as advertised & documented

Tags: google-api, google-people-api

Folks, I'm not sure if you are aware about this but `people.contactGroups.get` endpoint does not work at all. Even in API Explorer...

Here is an example of me querying `people.contactGroups.list` for the list of groups:
[image]

Now, lets flip the tables and switch to `people.contactGroups.get` endpoint call using the `resourceName` from the response below:

[image]

eek... what's the heck... you need it in format `contactGroups/xyz`? already, take that:

[image]

oops, that didn't work either...

Fine, move on and switch to `people.contactGroups.members.modify` endpoint and try modify our contact group there:

[image]
[image]
heck, heck... okay, here is your `contactGroups/xyz` format you're craving about:
[image]
[image]

It turns out these endpoints are exhibiting behavior neither consistent with the documentation nor with the internal implementation.

However, that somehow works gracefully in `Google Contacts`... Are you folks consuming for that some sort of internal APIs?

Is there anything wrong with what I'm doing or is it a bug in the APIs?

- UPD: It turns out only `people.contactGroups.batchGet` endpoint works as advertised and documented. All other `people.contactGroups.*` endpoints are prone to the very same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a bug with the configuration of the resource name. This has now been resolved, sorry about any inconvenience.

Comment: Oh, this is great - thanks a ton for the prompt response! Is the configuration change already deployed in prod?

Comment: Yes it is deployed! API explorer and all queries should work now.

Comment: Hmm... are we looking at the different API Explorer? The one I'm using still does not work and has the same erroneous behavior.

Here is the one I'm using: https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/contactGroups/get